# how to use data binding variable in styles.xml

Tags: android, data-binding, styles, android-databinding, nosuchmethoderror

can I use data binding variable in styles.xml?

I am trying to do like this :

```
<style name="keyboard_key_view">
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/key_height_600_tablet_port</item>
    <item name="backgroundRes">@drawable/keboard_key_selector</item>
    <item name="textColor">@color/kb_blue_letters</item>
    <item name="textSize">@integer/kb_text_size_600_dp</item>
    <item name="android:onClick">@{clickListener::onClick}</item>
</style>
```

it throws error

```
Could not find a method @{clickListener::onClick}(View) in the activity

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: @{clickListener::onClick} [class android.view.View]
```

can I achieve `onClick` in style using data binding or I must have to set this attribute in `layout.xml` only

Comment: AFAIK you can not .. Data binding first look for `<layout>` tag .. So you need to do this in layout xml ... NO binding in style no clickListener ..

Comment: Tx @ADM, for replying